# How to convert a string variable to QBrushStyle in Qt?

Tags: qt

I am passing it as a string but it does not function.

Comment: Hm, did you try `Qt::BrushStyle style;` where `style` is your variable?

Comment: Yes and it is not correct.

Comment: I think it is worth to be explained why it is not correct, how do you use it, and what is the error you got.

Comment: You seriously need to reword it to match what you meant to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually convert the string to style by doing a comparison:

```
Qt::BrushStyle brushStyle;

if (string == "Qt::SolidPattern")
    brushStyle = Qt::SolidPattern;
else if (string == "Qt::HorPattern")
    brushStyle = Qt::HorPattern;
else if
    ...
```

Comment: It's a perfectly correct code. What error do you get?

Comment: But how to pass it from the form to the brush style?

Comment: for example how to pass it from a combo box where items are stored as string?

Comment: I mean i have declared the Qt::BrushStyle brushStyle variable. The issue is how to pass the Qt::VerPattern selected from a QComboBox where it is stored as a string?

Comment: the error I get is quite understandable: assigning to 'Qt::BrushStyle' from incompatible type 'const QString'

Comment: You need to manually check the string for match with every style. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Qt::BrushStyle` is flagged with `Q_ENUM` so you can use `QMetaEnum` to go from and to a string:

```cpp
auto           const metaEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<Qt::BrushStyle>();
QString        const str      = metaEnum.key(Qt::SolidPattern);
Qt::BrushStyle const brush    = metaEnum.keyToValue(str);
```

`QVariant` can do the same:

```cpp
QVariant       const vBrush = QVariant::fromValue(Qt::SolidPattern);
QString        const str    = vBrush.toString();
Qt::BrushStyle const brush  = QVariant(str).value<Qt::BrushStyle>();
```